# Apple Calendar: Share busy/nonbusy information for several calendars

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, sharing

I have a set of calendars, which I would like to share together as busy/nonbusy. That is, I want others to see (on a single calendar) whether I am busy in any calendar at a given date or not.

This does not necessarily have to go through Apple Calendar, but I would like to keep using it. That is, if there's an external software, I hope I don't have to change too much of my current structure.

Nice-to-have: In case I'm busy, people could see which calendar caused that.

/EDIT

Several calendars are google-calanders that I read in, but then there is also some iCloud calendars (Standard iCloud + Facebook)

Comment: Tell us the source of the calenders, like are they from Google ?

Comment: It is strange that Mac calendar app does not support this. If it allows importing the data from other calendars (like google) why wouldn't it allow you to show as busy ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try the Google for that.

The explanations on how to will take to much space in here, but if you follow the [instructions here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/products.html#calendar), it is explained nicely.

[image: Google for business]

Comment: Thanks, but the calendars are not google-only. It probably needs to be some application that uses the Mac Calendars interface.

Comment: At the time of my answer that information was not available. So you have a mix  of calenders? including some that are "Local" to your mac (not shared) ?

Comment: Yes. Well, they are not local in the sense as they are synced over iCloud. 

For a second, I thought about sharing them with my google account and then proceeding, but that would be suboptimal for several reasons:

i) I'd need to redo the procedure whenever I add a calendar
ii) I could easily create a loop, since I am importing my google calendars to iCloud.

Comment: Got it.. we need to look for different answer than. I do not know how to do what you are asking.